# Converting images from one geospatial coordinate system to another

Tags: leaflet, geospatial

I'd like to stack the images from this map: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/regional/nca/soiltype/map/ from linear projection into a leaflet map.  The source tiles are in known but nonstandard zoom levels, and leaflet maps want mercator mercator XYZ tiles.  In principle, I know how to do this - I have functions for changing XY coordinates into lat-lng coordinates in the two maps, and I just need to map pixels for the target map in terms of pixels in the source map.

This is unfortunately nontrivial, as the source pixels are spread across hundreds of different image files, and I am trying to put them into hundreds more images.  Is there a software package that makes this a little bit more straightforward?  If there is no library for dealing with this kind of data, it seems like there really should be...

Comment: If you have XY co-ordinates of the images you want to put on a leaflet map, you should be able to convert them into pixel-space by applying an offset of the TL corner of the map to (0,0), or am I missing something?

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).

Answer (score 1):

Postgis has the [RT_ST_Transform](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/RT_ST_Transform.html) method, which under the hood uses [GdalWarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html). So, you have at least these two options. If you use Postgis, you will need to actually register/import the images into Postgis, using [raster2pgsql](http://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Loader) and then call RT_ST_Transform on each one and then dump them out again -- which could be scripted to some extent using plpgsql (Postgres's scripting language). There is something of a learning curve involved with using Postgis raster, which may be worthwhile if you plan to do any other image processing analysis. You could also write a shell script (or similar) to automate gdalwarp if you don't wish to go the Postgis route.

Answer (score 1):

For a less formal method than `gdalwarp` (an excellent program), you can check out the Leaflet plugin [Leaflet.imageTransform](https://github.com/ScanEx/Leaflet.imageTransform), that can transform and image on the fly in the browser.